# print everything after a slash

Tags: text-processing, sed

I found how to print everything before a slash, however I need to print everything after a slash. I have a string like `blablabal/important` and I need to print only `important`. 
How should I modify the line below to get printed everything after a slash and not before?

```
sed 's:/[^/]*$::'
```

Comment: You need to print everything after the first slash, or everything after the last slash?

Comment: @Kira Looks like last slash to me with `$` in the regex.

Comment: I have only one column in a test file. Each row is a string where slash appears only once.

Comment: Use the right tool for this job: `cut -d/ -f2- <infile`

Comment: @don_crissti Is there a reason `cut` is better than `sed` for this?

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann - isn't the reason obvious? i.e. `cut` was designed for this job (extracting one or more fields) while `sed` is a "general purpose tool" (so not optimized for this task) ; also, _regex is expensive_: if you had to process millions of records with hundreds of fields each you'd see the difference...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you mentioned in your comment that the file only has one slash, why not just use `awk`?

Example:

```
 ❱ echo "blablabal/important" | awk -F'/' '{print $1}'
blablabal
 ❱ echo "blablabal/important" | awk -F'/' '{print $2}'
important
```

Comment: This only prints the second part in a string with multiple slashes. Well, unfortunately that's what the asker wants…

Comment: Indeed. No reason to overcomplicate it with a `sed` replacement if there's only two results.

Answer (score 31):

Just delete everything until the last slash:

```bash
$ echo "blablabal/important" | sed 's:.*/::'
important
```

It also works with multiple slashes:

```bash
$ echo "blablabal/not/ver/interesting/important" | sed 's:.*/::'
important
```

Comment: `sed 's/.*\///'` may be more POSIX-standard.

Comment: @SopingLee thanks, but no, this is POSIX. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html: "Any character other than <backslash> or <newline> can be used instead of a <slash> to delimit the BRE and the replacement."

Comment: @Niing please ask a separate question, that is a different issue.

Answer (score 21):

It looks like the other answers are assuming that you have multiple lines of data in a file, which are all to be processed.  In this case `sed` or `awk` (or possibly `cut`) would be the best tools for processing all the lines in one go.

However, if you just have one line in a shell variable (assuming you're using `bash`), you can use shell expansions to achieve the desired result, without having to spawn utilities in external processes:

```
$ var="interesting/bla/blablabal/important"
$ 
$ # everything after the first slash:
$ echo "${var#*/}"
bla/blablabal/important
$ # everything after the last slash:
$ echo "${var##*/}"
important
$ # everything before the first slash:
$ echo "${var%%/*}"
interesting
$ # everything before the last slash:
$ echo "${var%/*}"
interesting/bla/blablabal
$
```

---

Alternatively, I assume your slash-separated strings are file paths.  If that is the case, you can use `dirname` and `basename` to get the path and filename components:

```
$ # everything before the last slash:
$ dirname "$var"
interesting/bla/blablabal
$ # everything after the last slash:
$ basename "$var"
important
$
```

Comment: How can I get the rest of the second last slash?

Comment: @JinKwon Are you referring to the "blablabal" substring in the above example?  If so you could do `basename $(dirname "$var")`

Answer (score 1):

This sould work:

```
echo "blablabal/important" | sed 's:[^/]*/\(.*\):\1:'
```

The first part `[^/]*`, matches everything BUT a slash, then we have a literal slash `/`, and a "matches everything" `.*` inside escaped parenthesis `\(.*\)`. The escaped parenthesis are there to "save" the matching result, meaning that it will contain everything after the first slash in this case. The `\1` refer to the first matched group, in this case we only have one group, because there is only one `\(...\)` pair.

In `sed`, the character you type after the `s` will be the delimiter. It is a common practice to use `/` as delimiter, but is this case it is easier to use something else, although it would be possible to use a slash too.

Comment: Yes, there are like 100 other ways to do that. I think terdon's answer might be the shortest with `sed`. `cut` would also be a good answer for this specific case.

Comment: you guys do exactly opposite things though - you get the first, he gets all.

Comment: True, that's why I've asked OP if he wanted everything after the first or last slash, but as there is only one slash per line in his case, it won't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed -et -e's|/|&\n|;//D' <in >out
```

...will print everything after the first slash on any line which contains one, or else print any other unmodified. If you drop the `//` it will only print lines it modifies.

You may need to use a literal `\n`ewline in place of the *`n`* in the `\n` escape though, depending on your `sed` version.

Also, if you specify an occurrence count...

```sh
sed -et -e's|/|&\n|num;/\n/D'
```

...you can delete up to the *num*th slash on a line without affecting any line which doesn't contain at least *num* slashes.

Answer (score 0):

grep solution:

```
$ echo "blablabal/important" | grep -oP "/\K.*"
important
```

\K drops the matched string in output